# Android Multi-Touch Not Responding

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am trying to build an application that uses multi-touch. I am using the `'getActionMasked()'`
to get the current action and then check if the pointer count is two.

How ever the code isn't working as I expect it to.

There are mainly two problems that I am facing.

1. The 'two-finger-touch' is not working at all.
2. The `'MotionEvent.ACTION_UP'` is not executing.

Here is the code :

```
imgs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent m) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Prevent false touch events
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (lastTime > -1 && (now - lastTime) < threshold) {
                    // Return if a touch event was receive less than "threshold" time ago
                    return true;
                }

                lastTime = now;

                switch(m.getActionMasked()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        td = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();
                        if (pointerCount == 2){
                            //Do Work here. [Not Working]
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //Do Work here. [Not Working]
                        return true;
                }
                return arg0.onTouchEvent(m);
            }
        });
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Looking forward to getting some help on this and some clarification on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you might want to check out the Android training material on multi-touch here -> http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html              ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is key to getting a 2nd finger recognized and you have none of that

Answer (score 0):

I think setOnTouchListener it's for single finger only,so you never get two fingers event.
You can use onTouchEvent(View v,MotionEvent e),

```
public class yourview extends view(
@Override  
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent m) {
    int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();
    switch (m.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        //case 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:             
             if (pointerCount == 2){
              //do what you want here.
             }
        //case
    }
    return true;
```

}